# For a clinical study, What statistical analysis methods should I add or change

Tags: clinical-trials

I am performing a statistical analysis of a clinical study where the dependent variable is a binary variable (whether or not a myocardial infarction occurred). As a novice, I first learned the following statistical analyses, but I would like to add new statistical analyses or replace previous studies with other analyses that will make my results different from the referenced statistical analyses (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12933-023-01870-z) different or better. Which statistical analysis methods should I add or change.

I refer to the following statistical analysis：https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12933-023-01870-z
The data set of the 3-year transition of the TyG index was analyzed and classified into 5 classes using K-means clustering. K-means clustering is a technique that has the goal of dividing N observations into K clusters. Each observation is assigned to the cluster with the closest mean value, which serves as the prototype of the cluster. As the number of categorized classes was increased, the maximum number of classes recruited was 5, with each class containing no less than two data. When the number of clusters equaled to 5, the effect of k-means clustering was better than others. Further categorization into final classes was performed for each of the 5 classes that met the criteria below: Class 1, the TyG index was from 8.01 in 2012 to 8.14 in 2015, representing better control of TyG index; Class 2, the TyG index was from 8.64 in 2012 to 8.41 in 2015, representing good control of TyG index; Class 3, the TyG index was from 8.68 in 2012 to 9. 17 in 2015, representing moderate control of TyG index; class 4, the TyG index was from 9.48 in 2012to 8.93 in 2015, from high level to low level, representing worse control for its higher cumulative TyG index than class 3; class 5, the TyG index was from 9.88 in 2012 to 9.93 in 2015, representing worst and terrible control of TyG index (Fig. 2).
Descriptive statistics (means and standard deviations, SD, for continuous data and percentages for categorical data) were used to report basic characteristics. The t-test or Mann-Whitney U test for continuous variables and the chi-squared test or Fisher’s exact test for categorical variables were used to analyze differences in baseline characteristics between classes. Univariate and multivariate logistic regression analysis were performed with factors important for stroke incidence. A restricted cubic spline model was then carried out for examining the shape of the correlation between cumulative TyG index and stroke. We chose four knots at 20th, 40th, 60th and 80th. Also, we performed several subgroup analyses and

Comment: This block of text is very hard to read. Can you please edit it for clarity? Also it's not clear where the stuff after " I refer to the following statistical analysis" comes from. Did you write this or it's a quote from somewhere?

Comment: I refer to the following articles for statistical analysis：https：//link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12933-023-01870-z

Comment: Thank you for the edits and the reference. However, you provide very little detail about the clinical study you are analyzing. Since you phrase your question very generally, you'd only get very general answers.

Comment: I'm concerned that your goal is to "add new statistical analysis (...) to make my results different". If you are analyzing data from an actual clinical study, your goal (obligation?) should be to do an appropriate and correct analysis. This might very well be close to the referenced statistical analysis. If you'd like to get help, please describe the study in meaningful detail.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to yourself as a "novice" and write:

> I would like to add new statistical analyses or replace previous
> studies with other analyses that will make my results different from
> the referenced statistical analyses

This is a terrible way to do things. The general way to do statistical analysis is (in very, very, broad outline)

1. Figure out what hypotheses you want to test or questions you want to answer
2. Figure out what data you need
3. Gather data
4. Do the tests and analyses

Now, you already have data. OK. But, unless you can either a) find something with the analysis that was done or b) find some new hypothesis you want to test or question you want to answer then there is no need to do more analyses.

The "I don't like their results, get me new ones" is not recommended.

From a quick read of the quoted text (I admit, I didn't go to the link) the analysis seems fine.